# Error Syntax when using foreach in update tag in mybatis

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, mybatis

Hi I am now using mybatis to construct dynamic sql in spring boot framework. and the database is mysql. I run it locally, the sql server is *MYSQL 8.0.21*. For mybatis, I am using(build.gradle)

```
    compile('org.mybatis:mybatis:3.4.6')
    compile('org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:1.3.2')
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.13')
```

When I was trying to do this in .xml file:

```
    <update id="update" parameterType="java.util.List" keyProperty="id">
        <foreach collection="list" item="answer" index="index" separator=";">
            UPDATE Answer
            SET RequestId=#{answer.requestId}, QuestionId=#{answer.questionId}, QuestionnaireId = #{answer.questionnaireId},
            AnswerText = #{answer.content}, AnswerChoiceId = #{answer.choiceId}, CreatedTime = #{answer.createdTime},
            LastUpdatedTime = #{answer.lastUpdatedTime}
            WHERE AnswerId = #{answer.id}
        </foreach>
    </update>
```

it is works fine if I just pass one item like this（**Json examples below just show you the fields, it doesn't mean I pass the values in this format, Actually, I convert the following examples as List in java**):

```
[
    {   
        "id": 2,
        "requestId": 2,
        "questionnaireId": 3,
        "questionId": 5,
        "content": "PROD",
        "choiceId": 8,
        "createdTime": "2020-08-04 20:50:41"
    } 
]
```

**but it will throw error when I add two items:**

```
[
    {   
        "id": 2,
        "requestId": 2,
        "questionnaireId": 3,
        "questionId": 5,
        "content": "PROD",
        "choiceId": 8,
        "createdTime": "2020-08-04 20:50:41"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "requestId": 2,
        "questionnaireId": 3,
        "questionId": 5,
        "content": "LAB",
        "choiceId": 7,
        "createdTime": "2020-08-04 20:50:41"
    }

]
```

The error saying:

```
 "\n### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE Answer\n            SET RequestId=2, QuestionId=5, QuestionnaireId = 3,\n  ' at line 7\n### The error may involve com.sample.demo.example.repository.mapper.AnswerMapper.update-Inline\n### The error occurred while setting parameters\n### SQL: UPDATE Answer             SET RequestId=?, QuestionId=?, QuestionnaireId = ?,             AnswerText = ?, AnswerChoiceId = ?, CreatedTime = ?,             LastUpdatedTime = ?             WHERE AnswerId = ?          ;              UPDATE Answer             SET RequestId=?, QuestionId=?, QuestionnaireId = ?,             AnswerText = ?, AnswerChoiceId = ?, CreatedTime = ?,             LastUpdatedTime = ?             WHERE AnswerId = ?\n### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE Answer\n            SET RequestId=2, QuestionId=5, QuestionnaireId = 3,\n  ' at line 7\n; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE Answer\n            SET RequestId=2, QuestionId=5, QuestionnaireId = 3,\n  ' at line 7",
```

**It seems error when iterating through the list?**
Also I cannot see any error in my code, can anyone help?

**Update**
I also tried to add a ";" at the end and also "BEGIN" and "END" . Still no luck

```
        BEGIN
        <foreach collection="list" item="answer" index="index" separator=";">
            UPDATE Answer
            SET RequestId=#{answer.requestId}, QuestionId=#{answer.questionId}, QuestionnaireId = #{answer.questionnaireId},
            AnswerText = #{answer.content}, AnswerChoiceId = #{answer.choiceId}, CreatedTime = #{answer.createdTime},
            LastUpdatedTime = #{answer.lastUpdatedTime}
            WHERE AnswerId = #{answer.id}
        </foreach>
        ;
        END;
```

One last question is:
I know this is not a batch operation. **So do loop in java or using this foreach in mybatis. which is better?** I was think using foreach maybe a litte bit faster?

Comment: Did you enable multi-query support? There is a connection property "allowMultiQueries" that is false by default. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: As for "which is better?", we usually recommend doing the loop in Java. If there are a large number of updates, a JDBC batch may perform better. But there are many variables and opinions about this, so you'll need to do some testing and decide for yourself which is "better".

Comment: @JeffButler Though possible, I would recommend to run each SQL statement separately. Well... unless there's a critical performance issue.

Comment: The primary goal of `<foreach>` is to assemble a single SQL statement, not to run multiple ones in a single call. If you want the latter I would recommend to batch multiple [separated] SQL statements instead.

Comment: @TheImpaler I believe that is exactly what I said :)